# has_secure_password cannot load such file -- bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, and working on a project to add sign up/sign in authentication for users...
I couldn't start rails servers because of "bcrypt". Then I upgraded the version of bcrypt in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11', require: false
```

Now the problem I'm having is when i go to '/signup' page is that it says: cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext

```
class User < ApplicationRecord    
  has_secure_password 
end
```

This error occurred while loading the following files:: **has_secure_password**

By the way, I'm on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Why did you specify `require: false` for the `gem` call? You then need to manually require `bcrypt` when you want to use it and maybe you are not doing that?

Comment: this is what I found in other solution.
without `require: false` rails server won't start

Comment: what is the error that you have with the rail server? if you have an error message you just solve it. You can even google the error message and you will find a solution on stackoverflow.

Comment: you should solve the server issue that you have with bckript then go to https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby and follow the instruction for bckript set up